# True/False for two arrays having 1+ values that are the same

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

***Edit note: The problem has changed slightly since first posting; see edit***

So I'm looking to check two arrays (of strings or integers/floats; although it'll be the same for both arrays) and get a True result if there's any overlap (i.e. if there's 1+ values that exist in both arrays).

So for example;

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3}
a2 = {4, 5, 2, 18}
```

These would return True as the value 2 exists in both. However;

```
b1 = { 9 }
b2 = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 }
```

These would return False as there's no value that exists in both b1 and b2.

Is there any way this can be done using formula, etc.?

***Edit:***

So I *think* I've been able to find a way to do this if the arrays are created within the formula itself; such that:

```
{=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH({1,2,3},{4,5,2,18},0)))}
{=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH({9},{1,1,2,3,5,8},0)))}
```

These return True and False respectively; and I can't see any unexpected behavior for the most part. However, if I try and use this formula with it pointing to cells containing arrays such as;

```
a1 -> ={1, 2, 3}
a2 -> ={4, 5, 2, 18}
a3 -> {=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(a1,a2,9)))}
```

then it fails. Therefore I feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about constant arrays; especially as;

```
c1 -> ={1, 2, 3}
c2 -> =sum(c1) -> 1
```

I'd expect c2 to give 6, and this is what I get if I do;

```
c3 -> =sum({1, 2, 3}) -> 6
```

So yeah, I'm clearly misunderstanding how arrays work but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

***Edit 2:***

Below is a screenshot showing how my data exists for the sum example (noting that cell C2 is set to text format just to show what's in the cell; when set to general the answer given is 1).

[Array issue - Sum example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7paSI.png)

Comment: What is literally in each cell? Does cell `A1` have this as it's literal contents: `{1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: At the moment it is literally that, although long term that will (probably) be replaced by a set of formulas which convert a string such as "1#2#3" into an array such that { "1", "2", "3"}

Comment: @BruceWayne I've updated my post; I think I've found a method that would work, but I also think I'm not quite getting arrays at a fundamental level

Comment: @Steve,, for better understanding share sample data,, Screen Shot to understand data placement !!

Comment: @RajeshS I've attached an image showing the final example in my post; if more screenshots would be helpful, let me know :)

Comment: @Steve ,, I think this will help you `=IFERROR(IF((A1=a2),TRUE),FALSE)` where cells has `a1 -> ={1, 2, 3}`
`a2 -> ={4, 5, 2, 18}`  ,, Formula will return FALSE ,, is that you are looking for??

Comment: @Steve,, confirm through comments or up vote comment to confirm that my formula help you so that I'll be able to post it as Answer !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85139/discussion-between-steve-and-rajesh-s).

Comment: To clarify; this problem is (as yet) unresolved

Comment: I think [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/813953-store-retrieve-multiple-values-one-cell.html) will do the `{=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(a1,a2,9)))}`.. good luck. ( :